# Add a constant to an std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl

I have an input signal which is an `std_logic_vector` and holds an address. I use it to read from the memory, I need to read 500 bits, but since my memory data bus is only 256 bit wide, I need to read two consecutive chunks of 256 bit. To do this I want to read the first time from the address stored in the signal, and the second time from the address 256 bits (32 Bytes) after the address stored. How do I add a constant number to an `std_logic_vector`:

```
ADRESS  : in std_logic_vector (0 to 31);

--code

--read first word:
dfmc_DDR2Interface_address <= ADRESS;
dfmc_DDR2Interface_read <= '1';

-- more code

--read second word (what I want to do)
dfmc_DDR2Interface_address <= ADRESS+32;
dfmc_DDR2Interface_read <= '1';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way out is to use the `numeric_std_unsigned` package:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;  -- if you add this...

entity add_integer_literal_to_slv_signal is
    port (
        address: in std_logic_vector(0 to 31);
        dfmc_DDR2Interface_address: out std_logic_vector (0 to 31);
        dfmc_DDR2Interface_read: out std_logic
    );
end;

architecture example of add_integer_literal_to_slv_signal is
begin
    --read first word:
    dfmc_DDR2Interface_address <= address;
    dfmc_DDR2Interface_read <= '1';

    -- more code

    --read second word (what I want to do)
    dfmc_DDR2Interface_address <= address + 256; -- ...this will work out of the box!
    dfmc_DDR2Interface_read <= '1';
end;
```

For the record, you should take a proper look into the numeric_std package. @JimLewis has a nice roundup on VHDL 2008 arithmetic:
http://www.gstitt.ece.ufl.edu/vhdl/refs/vhdl_math_tricks_mapld_2003.pdf

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to ask what an address means in the context of your design.

If, as I usually find, it represents an unsigned number, the cleanest answer is to declare Address as type Unsigned (from the numeric_std) library, or sometimes even as a ranged subtype of Natural.

Then addition of integers will simply work, with no fuss, and no issues with VHDL-2008 support on brain-dead tools.

In your testbench you may have to convert to std_logic_vector to connect to a poorly designed simulation model, but such conversions are likely to be few.